# Сборка темы WordPress

Tags: wordpress, themes

Совсем недавно стал работать с wp  и столкнулся с такой задачей: необходимо организовать структуру темы wp по аналогии с frontend проектом:

Scr
Public
. gitignor 
Сборка гальпом
И так далее в лучших традициях. Но при попытке переделать скелетон скаченный с underscores сервер кидает 500. 
Подскажите, в какую сторону гуглить? Сижу уже несколько часов ничего подходящего не вижу

Comment: "Scr Public . gitignor Сборка гальпом Переведи на понятный.

Comment: Структура папок, подключение гита, гальпом сборщик js, sass

Comment: Матчасть: https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC. И главное - http://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: > Сижу уже несколько часов ничего подходящего не вижу В документацию, естественно: [Создание тем](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC) Особое внимание [иерархии шаблонов](http://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2)